# GCM client unable to receive push notifications on Android

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

My Android client was unable to receive push notifications from GCM server even when `success:1`.
`multicast_id":8703499666074543637,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1439080356936445%9bd2607ff9fd7ecd"`

I followed this  [tutorial](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Google-Cloud-Messaging) . It follows the new implemetation of using GCM where :

> 1. In the app manifest, replace your GcmBroadcastReceiver with "com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver", and replace the current service declaration that extends IntentService to the new GcmListenerService
> 2. Remove the BroadcastReceiver implementation from your client code
> 3. Refactor the current IntentService service implementation to use GcmListenerService

I test my app for GCM push notifications using this  [link](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/gcm.html)  .

This is a part of my manifest for BroadcastReciever and IntentService:

```
<receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.usc.jay.ifff" />
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
       <service android:name="com.usc.jay.ifff.GCMIntentService"
        android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

My IntentService:

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GcmListenerService{
   public static final int MESSAGE_NOTIFICATION_ID = 435345;

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
        String message = data.getString("message");
        Loge.e("GCM",message);

        sendNotification(message);
    }


    private void sendNotification(String message) {
        int icon = R.mipmap.ic_launcher;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

        String title = this.getString(R.string.app_name);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("message", message);
        // set intent so it does not start a new activity
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, title, message, intent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        // Play default notification sound
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

        // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);

    }
```

Everytime I send a dowstream message, nothing shows on the logcat which means it did not arrive on the device. Please help. I tried to check every related questions on this and tried the answers but nothing works. It would be better if it really receive on the client side but it was not successful. Is there something wrong with my implemetation?

BTW, I get the registration id via getToken using the Instance Id API and not with the register method because it is now deprecated according to Google Developers.

Did I miss something? Please help.

Comment: Hi I hope you did start the gcm registration from your application. It would send it to the google and return the registration id to the application. this id send back to the third party backend server or use and other api as you did tried for send the message to the device.

Comment: @Jaye : Have you tried on different devices with different network? I mean if you have given manual IP to your device, it will cause this issue. Try to check with mobile data connection too.

Comment: @BhavdipPathar yes I did. I log it on the logcat then copy the registration id to my server. I am going to send the regid to the server via httppost eventually but right now i'm just testing my app if it realy can receive notifications. My server is in PHP and i think nothing's wrong with it.

Comment: @Jai No. I did not try that yet. I am using wifi on my device. I have only one device. I will try to use mobile data. Thanks.

Comment: @Jai Why does the network has something to do with this issue?

Comment: @Jaye : Actually sometimes when we are trying to connect number of devices while applying the same IP manually, It will push message on that device which is connected in last with that IP. So I assumed that may be you have set IP manually and if it conflicts with other device. So Is it working with mobile data for you?

Comment: @Jai no. My mobile data is unreliable and so slow, I cannot connect to other apps either. My devices/router  sets the IP automatically.

Comment: @Jai Did you mean the local IP address or the internet IP address?

Comment: @Jaye : Internet one only

Comment: Check the device logcat for something like:
"I/GCM     ( 6177): GCM message <package name> <id given in send request>"

If you see that it's likely a problem with your app. If not the message is not making it to your device for some reason.

Comment: @morepork I tried another device and it worked. Looks like there is no problem with my code. The device is the problem.